# How to compare extracted Boolean values in jmeter.?

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQjVI.jpg)

I have written using groovy code.
10,13,15 th line not working properly.
Combined,gropbilling values will come Boolean format.

When Combined and group billing values will come true with same index , that index value needed for me .

Comment: Start with rewriting your "vars.get('Combined_i')" to "vars.get('Combined_' + i)". Same goes for "GroupBilling". This way the value stored in 'i' will actually be used to provide correct variable names.

Comment: @GeorgeRylkov extremely awasome thanks 

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't post code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)
2. You need to amend your `vars.get('Combined_i')` to `vars.get('Combined_' + i)` and `vars.get('GroupBilling_i')` to `vars.get('GroupBilling_' + i)`
3. Additionally [`vars.get()` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get-java.lang.String-) will return a [String](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) you will need to cast it to boolean explicitly like:

   ```
   boolean Combined = vars.get('Combined_' + i) as boolean
   ```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)